# Cannot install ubuntu on my phone: "Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable"

Tags: apt, package-management, ubuntu-touch

I want to install ubuntu on my phone.  According to official website procedure, when I write this command, it shows some error:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ubuntu-device-flash : Depends: click-ubuntu-policy but it is not installable
                       Depends: ubuntu-snappy-cli but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Did you run `sud apt-get update` before?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 14.04.05 LTS.

Comment: I have run sudo apt-get update , too, but why it is showing this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your error can have many reasons. You provided less information. Please edit your question withdetails about yous Ubuntu version and a link to the tutorial, you used. I  try to show up some possible reasons and solutions:

I am not an expert, but your log shows, that you have unmet dependencies. This could be, because you  have installed some packages from externalsources or you did something else what a beginner should not do.;)

You told us, that you are running an old version of Ubuntu. Maybe a system upgrade will help to solve your problem. Try to upgrade with: `sud apt-get dist-upgrade` or use the 'software updater' http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade

The second idea is to do a full release upgrade. This could be done with the software updater, too. Or use this command: `sudo do-release-upgrade` (May be you need to change your setup to receive non-LTS-versions)

Your error shows, that the dependency cannot be fulfilled, because some packages cannot be installed. Maybe you added a wrong ppa sources. Please provide your ppa lists by executing `cat /etc/apt/sources.list && cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d` and then insert the output to your question.

Feel free to ask for more information and instructions within a comment,.

Comment: Bro.. I have resolved this problem ,but again a problem occurred. I cannot unlock my phone's boot loader, as my volume keys are not  responding during fast boot mode.... Hence I cannot perform further procedure ..

Comment: Please open a new question for this new problem. And please tell us how you solved your first question. If my answer has helped, vote it up and check it as 'answered'. Otherwise answer your question on your self by providing your solution. This is, how Stack-exchange works.;)